# Javascript: Callback Functions

Tags: javascript, callback

What is an analogy used to explain callback in javascript to a layman person? I am a 13 year old coder trying to explain anonymous functions to people without knowledge of coding how can I explain callback functions without using any technical terms.

Comment: Notice that callback doesn't necessarily mean an anonymous function expression. You can first declare a function and then pass it by name as well - that might help for people who aren't too familiar with the syntax.

Comment: an alarm clock is a callback from sleeping when the condition of needing to go to work is fulfilled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You go to a library to borrow a book.
- They don't have the book since someone already took it.
- Instead of waiting for the book for 4 days there, you go home. When they have the book - they call you back.

That's a callback.

Comment: Isn't it more like giving the library people a sheet of paper where you've noted what to do when the book arrives? You might write "give me a call" or "send book per post" or whatever…

Comment: The library is the one managing it, you're only telling them to call you back, they can have a sheet or whatever alternative they want :)